# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project.users'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

** New user to SOF, sorry for poor post and thank you in advance for any help**

As the title says. I have been through multiple threads of StackOverflow with similar questions and none of them have given me a working solution.

[My directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKoy7.png)
The problem doesn't start until I add line18 into [urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSBT8.png)
and the error: 
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named django_project.users" is displayed.

I have tried different variations of importing the module and all seem to fail. 
[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o7Br.png)

I was following this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4jPR-M0TAQ&t=753s
it wasn't until 14:00 where I was getting errors the author of the video was not. I have been following his tutorial from the beginning and have not run into any errors until now. I have been trying to find a solution for about 4 days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have pushed the most recent code to github and made the repository temporarily public for anyone who wants to replicate this problem:
https://github.com/ChristopherMillones/PyTest

EDIT: [settings.py -> INSTALLED_APPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwsos.png)

Comment: There's not enough information here. We need to know at least where you're trying to import this module from, as the most common issues are that you're trying to relative import from the wrong level of directory.

Comment: Have you added your apps to django settings?

Comment: You need to be more thorough with your questions. Add your traceback.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As others mentioned, it would be helpful to provide some more context. Also, this error could also occur when you have a circular reference in the code (i.e two files importing each other at the top) (in which case, the error description may also be misleading)

Comment: My apologies, I published by accident without finishing the post. It is not finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django_project` is your project root directory.

The apps inside are `django_project`, `blog` and `users`.

If you added those to your `settings.py` you have to import "stuff" from it like

```
from users.models import MyModel
```

In your project itself (`django_project/django_project/*`) you don't have a module `users`, that's why the error is thrown.

Comment: Have uploaded the full question. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Have you tried changing your `urls.py` from `from django_project.users import ...` to `from users import ...`? That should fix it as said in the answer. :)

Comment: Wait. It works, but I am really confused as to why the first import didn't work, can you elaborate?

Comment: One of your apps is `django_project` (located in `PYTest/django_project/django_project/*` and there you have no submodule named `users`/`blog`. You can import the apps configured in `INSTALLED_APPS`, like `users`, etc.